# Cat pooping under the bed

Tags: cats

We recently got a new Shepherd Dog and now mycat. is scared to go to the litter box.  She has decided to poop under the bed.  Is there a spray or product out there that will make her stop.  she is stressd out but there has to be something we can do.

Answer (score 2):

My advice here would be:

**Reduce your cats stress!**

A new family member no matter whether it is a dog, cat or human can be stressful for a cat. What I think is most important:

1. Make your cat and dog get along or atleast accept each others presence
2. Move the litterbox to a place where the dog cannot get, maybe even get another one so the cat can choose the one where she does not have to pass by the dog to get there.
3. Maybe move the litterbox to the bedroom for now if it is the cats hiding place.

If your cat is house trained and suddenly goes on the floor anway it is always a sign of something being wrong. You have to make her understand that everything is ok, the dog is not a danger or bother and she will go back to "normal". I mean would you dare go to the bathroom if someone put a huge, easily excited fluffball in your home?

Tips on how to make dog and cat get along can be found all over this forum

[Senior cat and full grown dog](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/12285/how-to-introduce-a-newly-resident-cat-to-regularly-visiting-dog/12288#12288)

[Introducing cat to dogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1718/how-can-i-introduce-a-cat-into-a-household-with-dogs) It is about getting a cat but the answer is still good